# How to make my extension which should allow the ability to install in any scheme?

Tags: postgresql

The extension should not be movable, but should allow the possibility of installation in any scheme. Here's my code: https://github.com/CraigTyle/Mathexp. (complex - 1.0.sql - the foundation of the entire extension).

Comment: No schema is mentioned in the SQL script, so you should just say `relocatable = false` in the control file. What problems do you encounter with that?